# Google Authenticator as single login method

Tags: android, ios, security, authentication

Most developers seem to provide Google Authenticator as the second factor for authentication.

**Are there technical or security reasons why not to use Google Authenticator as the one and only source for authentication?**

In oder words: May I drop conventional UserID/Password entry and replace it by the entry of a Google Authenticator token?

> Google Authenticator is an application, which generates one (short)
>   time passwords (tokens) **locally on a smartphone**.
>
> The verification of
>   passwords can be done by your own web-server or application.
>
> **Google is by no means involved**: 
>   Neither generates tokes using their servers nor
>   verifies tokens using their servers.

How to set up Google Authenticator using an app:

- Initialize using a QR Code

[image: Sample QR Code]

- Then each time you open Google Authenticator, it generates a new toke

[image: Google Authenticator screenshot]

- Finally, user enters the code on your site and you verify it locally on your server [no Google server involved]

References:

- [PHP library to verify tokens made by Google Authenticator](https://github.com/chregu/GoogleAuthenticator.php)
- [Open Source version of Google Authenticator](https://github.com/google/google-authenticator)
- App for [Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.authenticator2&hl=de) and [iOS](https://itunes.apple.com/de/app/google-authenticator/id388497605?mt=8)
- [As explained by Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Authenticator)

Comment: I don't have and don't want a Google login, does that answer your question?

Comment: @PoulBak Google Authenticator is a generator for one (short) time passwords. By no means, you login using Google services. Google Authenticator is free an open source. It's algorithm is too.

Comment: I think he is just talking about google login. And as it was already pointed out, yes, you can, the same as some apps just allow facebook login, but many users dont have or dont want to use their google login (or facebook, or twitter, or sina weibo, ...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't feasible to remove the username as you need to lookup and validate what the one-time password should be for a particular user. By not requesting a username, you expose yourself to a number of issues:

1. Google Authenticator generates a six-digit number for each user that changes every thirty seconds. If you don't first confirm which user is logging in, an attacker can guess any 6 digit number at a time and they would gain access if it matches any of your users. The smaller number of users, the more difficult it is to guess, but there is always the chance that an attacker guesses a number that is a valid password (if you had a million or more users, it is possible that at one point in time they would all have a different OTP and any guess by an attacker would be valid).
2. By requiring identification of a specific user through username & password first, you are ensuring the risk of guessing correctly is limited to a single number at any time (1 in a million chance) and that such a guess is only possible when valid details are first obtained.
3. It is possible and likely that at some points in time more than one user would have the same one-time password assigned, meaning you would not be able to determine which user is actually trying to authenticate. You would also not be able to distinguish an authorised user from an attacker who had simply guessed a correct number.

If you only use Google Authenticator you are also losing the benefit of two two-factor authentication.

When using a password in combination with a one-time password, you are validating that the user has something she should know (password) and something she should have (her phone), which makes up the two factors. The possibility that an attacker could compromise both of these factors is very low as the one time password is continually changing.

When you are using both password and OTP you are also protected if either her phone is stolen or the password is compromised (phished or otherwise) as the attacker will not have access to the other factor necessary to authenticate.

Comment: Thank you, David! All granted! I don't intend to drop the whole userID. I just want to replace the password by the GA Token. Thus, I want to know, which if userID+GAToken ist less secure than userID+password.

Comment: Hi SteAp, yes it still is, but not quite as bad. You lose the benefit of a two factor auth, so if the phone or other device used to generate the code is stolen you will be compromised. Remember also that a password can be letters and numbers, symbols, caps and no caps, whereas the Google OTP is only a six digit number. This means that there are only a million password combinations instead of 95 to the power of 8 (3025989069143040 combinations). So a brute force attack would only have to send you a million requests worst case. This is mitigated by the 30sec change but still less secure

Comment: For completeness, it's also worth mentioning that if you lockout after a number of incorrect tries you can add significant protection to either of these methods.